# SQL Server Reorganize Index Job

Tags: sql-server

I have an index reorganize job on SQL Server 2012 that fails because page level locking is disabled on it.  My three questions are:

1. Why would page level locking be disabled on an Index?
2. If I go ahead and make changes and allow page level locking, it is not going to break anything, right?
3. Is there a script to make all the indexes allow page level locking?

Comment: Have you considered using [Ola Hallengren's database maintenance scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/)?

Comment: You could make 'Corporate policy' watch this. [Why Defragmenting Your Indexes Isn’t Helping](https://groupby.org/conference-session-abstracts/why-defragmenting-your-indexes-isnt-helping/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would page level locking be disabled on an Index?

By default, [allow_page_locks] is set to 1, so, someone must have changed it in the past to avoid that level of locking.

> If I go ahead and make changes and allow page level locking, it is not going to break anything, right?

I would test this in a non-prod environment prior to changing.  I would think the outcome would be unexpected locking.

> Is there a script?

You could use this script to identify those indexes and then change it to modify those.  But, I would think there was probably a good reason for the change in the first place.

```
Select Indx.name,
    Indx.type_desc,
    Indx.is_disabled,
    Indx.allow_page_locks,
    Indx.allow_row_locks 
from sys.indexes Indx
left outer join sys.objects OBJ 
    on OBJ.object_id=Indx.Object_id
where allow_page_locks = 0
```